# ivreg or ivprobit for binary variables?

Tags: r, variables, regression, instruments

I am estimating causal effect of participation on training on employment, where participation is binary variable, outcome (employment) is binary and existence of training in a city is binary. Is ivprobit function in R suitable for this non-linear model or I can use ivreg?

I tried `ivprobit` but I get error message in R

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I would appreciate information or links for ivprobit, I am not sure where to include city and year fixed effects in the code. Thanks.